# What is the good way to pass a value from form creation function to its submit handler?

Tags: 7, forms

I am newbie in Drupal, I have a query that i want to pass some value from form creation function to its submit handler.

Right now, I am saving that value in a form element of hidden type.

```
$form['product_nid'] = array(
 '#type' => 'hidden',
 '#value' => 12,
)
```

But this is not safe, anyone can change value on client side.

Comment: Basically you are asking for the most secure way, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to do by using $form_state['storage'],

Just define $form_state['storage']['something'] = ;
This value will not show in browser and You will get this value in submit handler. see this code you will understand.

```
/**
 * Returns the form.
 */
function my_module_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('my_module_my_form');
}

/**
 * Returns the render array for the form.
 */
function my_module_my_form($form_state) {

  $form_state['storage']['product_nid'] = 12;

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Save',
  );
}

/**
 * Add a submit handler/function to the form.
 *
 * This will add a completion message to the screen when the
 * form successfully processes
 */
function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $product_nid = $form_state['storage']['product_nid'];   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`value`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#val) instead, like this:

```
$form['product_nid'] = array(
 '#type' => 'value',
 '#value' => 12,
)
```

Elements of `value` type are never send to HTML, they are there just for what you are doing - passing values not meant to be changed by your user or scripts.

For complicated data, use [answer by Akash Jain](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171267/16495) instead. Way he proposed is the only practical one for objects and arrays. On the other hand, for simple strings or integers it's too complicated. Especially if later they are meant to be treated in the same way as user input. Then, use `value` fields.